# How to construct a regex for filenames to not have special characters and limited length?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am looking for a regular expression to make sure that my filenames do not contain special characters and are limited to length 9.

I am using `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,9}[a-zA-Z0-9]$` but it’s not able to match a single character like “a”.

Comment: This will need at least two chars to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the first character can be made optional by surrounding it with parentheses `()` and then appending a question mark `?`. To not include this as a capturing group, use `?:` after the opening bracket:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,9}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Solves my problem..!!